# HttpWebRequest Sharepoint API Authentication FedAuth 401

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 401, cookie

I already asked this question on StackOverflow [Question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234237/httpwebrequest-sharepoint-api-authentication-fedauth-401), but now I think I should have ask my question here in the first place.

I did some changes since I ask for help on SO, and my question is a bit different now.

This is the code I have

```
var adfsHelper = new ADFSHelper();
            var cookie = adfsHelper.GetFedAuthCookie(domainName, userName, password);
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (RemoteCertificateValidationCallback)Delegate.Combine(ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback((object SearchOption, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslerror) => true));

            var requestUri = "https://sharepoint/site/...._api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/items?$filter=SomeKey eq 'SomeValue'";
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
            httpWebRequest.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko";
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
            httpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
            httpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            httpWebRequest.Accept = @"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,*/*";
            httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            httpWebRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);

            try
            {
                HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                // Get the stream associated with the response.
                Stream receiveStream = endpointResponse.GetResponseStream();
                // Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
                StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                Console.WriteLine("Response stream received.");
                Console.WriteLine(readStream.ReadToEnd());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
```

My authentication workflow is the following, Request FedAuth token to the adfs server, then send it to the Sharepoint site insite my cookie.

I can browse the List with my IE, If I try use the cookie generated from my browser inside my code, I still have the 401 error.

Did I miss something?

Comment: am asking about ADFSHelper() , am tring to get the FedAuth Cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,

The _trust/ base url was the wrong one :/ With the correct URL it is now working :)

This question can now at least be used as a reference how to send FedAuth Cookie :)